# __LINE__ is not constexpr in MSVC

Tags: c++

**Update 28NOV2022**

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.34.31933 for x86
```

This issue seems to be sorted.

**Original Post**

ok, the latest VS 2019 Community, local "all defaults" C++ console project:

```
int main()
{
    // cl Version 19.21.27702.2 for x86
    // 
    constexpr auto MSCVER = _MSC_VER; // 1921
    constexpr auto MSCFULLVER = _MSC_FULL_VER; //192127702
    constexpr auto MSCBUILD = _MSC_BUILD; // 2
    /*
    : error C2131:  expression did not evaluate to a constant
    : message :  failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
    : message :  see usage of '__LINE__Var'
    */
    constexpr auto LINE = __LINE__;
}
```

But. Seemingly the same compiler on Godbolt compiles this ok. As ever before.

https://godbolt.org/z/rn44rN

Any idea?

**The Status as of 2019-07-22**

Apparently, this is a bug which is a feature. Ugh. And there is a macro which is almost perfect, besides the fact it casts to int, and the type of the **LINE** is long. Here is my version:

```
#define _DBJ_CONCATENATE_(a, b) a ## b
#define _DBJ_CONCATENATE(a, b)  _DBJ_CONCATENATE_(a, b)

#define CONSTEXPR_LINE long(_DBJ_CONCATENATE(__LINE__,U))
```

Original is [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/195665/-line-cannot-be-used-as-an-argument-for-constexpr.html). I had almost the same solution, but I was adding a zero instead of U. Perhaps because I spent hours trying to figure out what is going on.

I am sorry, but the reasoning of the MSVC team on that page is just strange. I am wondering is there a detail in the standard which resolves this issue.

Many thanks to commenters for pointing me in the right direction. But there is this remaining mistery: How come Godbolt + MSVC, has no problems with this same code?

Comment: Which year of MSVC?

Comment: [Might be helpful](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/195665/-line-cannot-be-used-as-an-argument-for-constexpr.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this is [already a known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/195665/-line-cannot-be-used-as-an-argument-for-constexpr.html) by the MSVC community:

> We have a known bug for this issue on the C++ team here. The status on this Developer Community item will be updated as that bug is looked at. Thanks again for reporting this to us.

Apparently, it is considered a "feature" of the compiler:

> The bug is considered a feature: Edit-and-Continue has a small but vocal and enthusiastic group of users (mostly game developers)

A user in the linked thread offers the following as a workaround:

> ```
> #define CAT(X,Y) CAT2(X,Y)
> #define CAT2(X,Y) X##Y
>
> #define USABLE_LINE int(CAT(__LINE__,U)) 
> //appending 'U' shouldn't change much as __LINE__ is supposedly non-negative anyway
> ```

Comment: _Edit-and-Continue has a small but vocal and enthusiastic group of users_ I'm not sure how that relates to this, but that group includes me.  It's very useful when debugging.

Comment: I take no sides on Edit-and-continue. I don't even know what it is. I'm just quoting the guy in the link 

Comment: @Chipster many thanks, Paul Sanders, there are more things in other ide's that are "very useful for debugging" but they do not change the compiler to achieve that.

Answer (score 7):

The MSVC team points out in that link that if you change the "Debug Information Format" from "/ZI" (Program Database for Edit and Continue) to "/Zi" (Program Database) this also fixes it (but disables edit and continue).  It worked for me.

If you're not using Edit and Continue this seems like the right fix.

Comment: Thanks, Eric, but I see nothing new in this answer? And it already got +1 ... Well SO works in mysterious ways ...

Comment: The compiler option fix is listed in the links but nowhere in the comments or answers above that I could find.  Wanted to make sure it was listed here since it was definitely the best answer for me.